# How to set a name for pairing bluetooth with OS-X

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm using my Mac as a bluetooth central manager (using CBCentralManager) and my iPhone as a LE peripheral.

Problem is when I'm making a secure connection between them I get on the iPhone screen a general name (showing the network MAC) and not a name that have a meaning. On the Mac I can see the service I'm advertising from the peripheral so it's fine.

Attached is a screenshot of what I get (I've deleted the MAC address from screenshot).

[image: iPhone Screenshot of the name]

How can I change this general name (if there is an option to) to something that has more meaning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name is set by the device you are connecting to... 
each device can modify its own name

Comment: but the ma should have its hostname set AFAICS